# Calculate Length for Unique Combinations of Four Columns by Specific value of Fifth Column

Tags: r

I have some data on 85,000 individuals. Each individual is assigned a rating. This rating is based on weights specified in each of four columns. The value in each column can range from 0 to 50. What I need is a table that lists the total number of individuals for each unique combination of values in the four columns.

```
Individual Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1          50    0    0    0
2          40   10    0    0
3          40   10    0    0
4          30   10   10    0  
5          30   10   10    0  
6          30   10   10    0
```

So the result will be

```
length   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1        50    0    0    0
2        40   10    0    0
3        30   10   10    0
```

I suspect that this should be very easy and that collapse will yield what I need but perhaps so will ddply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library("dplyr")

df=read.table(header = T, text="Individual Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
1          50    0    0    0
2          40   10    0    0
3          40   10    0    0
4          30   10   10    0  
5          30   10   10    0  
6          30   10   10    0  ")


df %>% 
    group_by(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4) %>%
    summarise(Length=n())
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a data table

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, .(length = .N), by = names(df[-1])]
#    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 length
# 1:   50    0    0    0      1
# 2:   40   10    0    0      2
# 3:   30   10   10    0      3
```

And since you asked about `ddply`, you could do

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, names(df)[-1], summarise, length = length(Individual))
#   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 length
# 1   30   10   10    0      3
# 2   40   10    0    0      2
# 3   50    0    0    0      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `base R` solution

```
aggregate(Individual ~.,  df, length)
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Individual
#1   50    0    0    0          1
#2   40   10    0    0          2
#3   30   10   10    0          3
```